# Why is the RecyclerView in Fragment is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have been working on an app. The RecyclerView is not getting inflated in the FragmentActivity. I think there's a minor mistake. Could you please check if there's any mistake? The app is not crashing when launched.

Thank you.

Fragment xml file - fragment_ftab2.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#121517"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ftab2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/course_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#24282b"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/q_str_lay1"
            android:background="#24282b"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#24282b"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_q_exp_lay1"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#24282b"
                android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:text="The Foundation"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but_q_exp_lay1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/classes_tv_1"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#24282b"
                android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:text="2 CLASSES"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#88898A"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/r1foundation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14.5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13.5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Fragment java file - ftab2.java

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.athrved.masterclass.uiux.FreeHelperClass;
import com.athrved.masterclass.uiux.FreeclassesAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ftab2 extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    RecyclerView foundRecycler;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter1;

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public ftab2() {
    }


    public static ftab2 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ftab2 fragment = new ftab2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftab2, container, false);
        foundRecycler =(RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.r1foundation);
        foundationRecycler();


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftab2, container, false);
    }

    private void foundationRecycler() {
        foundRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        foundRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        ArrayList<FoundHelperClass> freeLocatio = new ArrayList<>();

        freeLocatio.add(new FoundHelperClass(R.drawable.secndone, "Colour and Colour Theory - Fundamentals of Visual Design", "In this lesson, goutam explains everything you need to know about colours in UI/UX design. At the end he would also explain about the process of creating a colour palette."));
       // freeLocatio.add(new FoundHelperClass(R.drawable.firstone, "Design in Everyday Life", "In this lesson, goutam explains everything you need to know about colours in UI/UX design. At the end he would also explain about the process of creating a colour palette."));

        adapter1 = new FoundclassesAdapter(freeLocatio);
        foundRecycler.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
}
```

Adapter - FoundHelperClass.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.athrved.masterclass.uiux.PopHelperClass;
import com.athrved.masterclass.uiux.PopclassesAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FoundclassesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoundclassesAdapter.FoundViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<FoundHelperClass> featloc;

    public FoundclassesAdapter(ArrayList<FoundHelperClass> featloc) {
        this.featloc = featloc;
    }

    @NonNull

    @Override
    public FoundViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.course_str_card_design,parent,false);
        FoundViewHolder FoundViewHolder = new FoundViewHolder(view);

        return FoundViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoundViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FoundHelperClass FoundHelperClass = featloc.get(position);
        holder.fimage.setImageResource(FoundHelperClass.getFimage());
        holder.ftitle.setText(FoundHelperClass.getFtitle());
        holder.fdesc.setText(FoundHelperClass.getFdesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return featloc.size();
    }

    public static class FoundViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView fimage;
        TextView ftitle, fdesc;
        Button fbookmark_border, fbookmark;

        public FoundViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            fimage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fffimage);
            ftitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ffftitle);
            fdesc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fffdesc);

            fbookmark=itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
            fbookmark_border=itemView.findViewById(R.id.save_done);


            fbookmark_border.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(getAdapterPosition()==0){
                        fbookmark_border.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fbookmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if(getAdapterPosition()==1){
                        fbookmark_border.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fbookmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });

            fbookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(getAdapterPosition()==0){
                        fbookmark_border.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fbookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if(getAdapterPosition()==1){
                        fbookmark_border.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fbookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (getAdapterPosition() == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("VIDEOID", "_vAmKNin0QM");
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        Activity activity = (Activity) itemView.getContext();
                        activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

                    }

                    if (getAdapterPosition() == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("VIDEOID", "lrcqt4RelJ4");
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        Activity activity = (Activity) itemView.getContext();
                        activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: your onCreateView should return the `v` object and not inflate again

Comment: Could you try to palce the recycler view as a sibling of the scroll view? being inside another scrollable view will make it impossible for the recycler view to know the max height it can have